# Trouble filtering in Camel

Tags: spring, routes, apache-camel, messaging

I am attempting to filter out the null bodies from my route. The route polls from the function every half second or so. So, I get this error in my console also every half-second. 
Here is the stack trace:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                            Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [browserBean                                                                       ] [         0]
[route1            ] [filter1           ] [filter[simple{(${body} == null)}]                                             ] [         0]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   ------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
Id                  ID-CO183LTCS06-54352-1403798372606-0-1058
ExchangePattern     InOnly
Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-CO183LTCS06-54352-1403798372606-0-1057,     CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
BodyType            null
Body                [Body is null]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.hello.integration.GreetingController.greeting(GreetingController.java:15)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
at     org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67)
at     org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorPollingConsumer.receive(ProcessorPollingConsumer.java:58)
at     org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorPollingConsumer.receiveNoWait(ProcessorPollingConsumer.java:    66)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumer.poll(DefaultScheduledPollConsumer.java:48)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at     java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown     Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown     Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any Ideas? I feel like it's simple but I've been looking all over the web for solutions and can't find anything that solves my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

    http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi/camel-osgi.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="browserBean"/>
        <filter>
            <simple>${body} == null</simple>
            <stop/>
        </filter>
    <to uri="jms:queue:testQSource"/>
    <to uri="myBean"/>
    <log message="Routing message from testQSource to testQDestination queue with data ${body}"/>
    <to uri="jms:queue:testQDestination"/>
    <to uri="finalBean"/>
    <log message="message: ${body}"/>
</route>
</camelContext>

<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
<camel:template id="camelTemplate" />
</camel:camelContext>

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>\

<bean id="myBean" class="com.example.integration.modifier"/>
<bean id="finalBean" class="com.example.integration.ActionApp"/>
<bean id="browserBean" class="com.hello.integration.GreetingController"/>

</beans>
```

EDIT: The null body is coming from the following function:

```
package com.hello.integration;

import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {


    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        //Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}
```

Even though I attempt filter out the null bodies, I am still getting the error. Am I filtering them out too late?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put the filter inside of from tag. The below route should work :)

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="browserBean"/>

        <filter>
            <simple>${body} == null</simple>
            <stop/>
        </filter>

    <to uri="jms:queue:testQSource"/>
    <to uri="myBean"/>
    <log message="Routing message from testQSource to testQDestination queue with data ${body}"/>
    <to uri="jms:queue:testQDestination"/>
    <to uri="finalBean"/>
    <log message="message: ${body}"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Thanks Willem! Unfortunately, even after implementing that clever route, I am still getting the same error. I have edited my question to reflect the change in my route, as well as posting the stack trace and the function that is returning null. I'd really appreciate it if you'd take a look.

Comment: I only want to pick up one message at a time. I will only be sending one message from the browser/UI app. Then it will become a consumer instead of a producer. I'm not sure how to configure camel to only look when there is something to pick up or to only pick something up if something is there.

Comment: I think you may consider to use producer template to send the message to camel route instead of call the browserBean from the camel route.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a choice clause, as another way to do it. Here is an example:

```
      <route>
          <from uri="direct:routePublishedResponse"/>
          <bean ref="caseHearingHandler"/>
          <choice>
             <when>
                <simple>${body} != null</simple>
                <to uri="direct:resultSubRoute">
             </when>
             <otherwise>
                <log message="skipping due to NULL body" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
             </otherwise>
          </choice>
       </route>
```