# Trying to stop Camel exchange processing based on filter

Tags: apache-camel

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420660/trouble-filtering-in-camel) but the solution there does not work for me here - I am trying to use the filter EIP to discard selected exchanges. My routes look like (edited down for clarity):

```
from("{{fromSource}}")
 .convertBodyTo(RequestInterface.class)
 .enrich(INVOKE_BACKEND_URI, combiner)
 .to("{{toDestination}}");

from(INVOKE_BACKEND_URI)
 .to(backendUri)
 .filter().method(DiscardResponse.class).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Discarding undesired response").stop().end()
 .convertBodyTo(BodyInterface.class);
```

When the filter does NOT select the message, all is well - the log() is not displayed and the message goes to the convertBodyTo() and then back to the main route.

However, when the filter DOES select the message, the log() text is displayed but the exchange still continues on to the convertBodyTo() where it throws an exception because it's a message that shouldn't be there. The stop() appears to either not be executed or has no affect.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: The answers below will work, but why doesn't stop() work, above?

Comment: Could it be that you have an end() after the stop()?

Comment: I removed the end() and it made no difference.

Comment: Seems strange, I have used stop() in a similar code and that worked. You could report it as a bug and let the Camel developers answer.

Comment: Thanks Souciance - that motivated me to write a small reproducer which, of course, works fine. It does stop there... so I dug deeper into my example above, and the problem there is that the aggregation strategy (combiner, above) is still called with the 'stopped' exchange. Does that make sense?

Comment: I ran my reproducer test (which always works) in debug and the default aggregation strategy also is called with the stopped message, so I'm taking that it's normal. Is this what you would expect? The docs don't mention this case... that if the enricher stops processing, the aggregation strategy is still called.

Comment: Hmm so the combiner is actually doing some aggregation? That would make sense. The stop will then stop the current exchange but there is another exchange from the next aggregation step so that will continue. In that case you will probably need to add some function to break from the aggregation and then stop everything.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible from within a Processor to do this in order to stop the exchange:

```
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Since I'm not used to writing my routes using Java DSL I don't know if that option is available directly on the exchange within the route, but it probably is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way could be:

```
from(INVOKE_BACKEND_URI)
 .to(backendUri)
 .filter().method(DiscardResponse.class).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Discarding undesired response")
.choice()
  .when(simple("${property.Exchange.FILTER_MATCHED}=true")
   .stop()
.end()
 .convertBodyTo(BodyInterface.class);
```

Take a look at the bottom of the doc here:
http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html